# How to encode video for desktop/application recording?

Tags: video, video-encoding, screen-recorder

Which video encoder or which encoding technique would return the best quality/size value (or just the most "natural feel") for recorded desktop/application activity like video tutorials?

By good quality, I mean:

- good font readability
- no "artifacts"
- good quality of parts that don't change for a long period of time (e.g. inactive window areas).

Assume that the recorded view consist of only "gui-connected" elements like text areas, buttons, but not images, videos, animations.

Comment: Do you have any constraints regarding file size or bit rate?

Comment: Since you ask for an encoder, i will post this as a comment. Codec-wise there is TSCC available from Techsmith. This is used in Camtasia Studio etc. and specializes on the kind of content you have. The codec itself seems to be freely available: http://www.techsmith.com/download.html

Comment: No, just best quality to bitrate ratio in this application. The single criteria can be video size at least 640 x 480 px, or encoder for just full screen resolution recording.

Comment: @TheUser1024 I believe this is quite a constructive question with specific requirements regarding quality. Not much subjectivity there, in my opinion. Maybe you can explain what the codec does and why it's good, etc.

Comment: Sorry, i have used it in the past (years back), but i am unable to provide much detail. I just think it is worth a look, since Camtasia is a (widely used since a long time) app for capturing desktop videos for creating video tuts and they "invented" the codec for that purpose. So the chance of it being what @killer_PL is looking for is rather high. And since i have not used Camtasia itself, i cannot really say anything about that. I would not be surpised though, if someone told me Camtasia was the "Photoshop" of that kind of app. But i don't know that.

Comment: Currently I'm working with [Fast Stone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm). It seems good enough to capture or record your PC screen. I like it because it seems fast enough, supports upto 20 fps, and fits the resolution of screen. In addition, it also records audio if your laptop has an inbuilt microphone...

Comment: You didn't mention what OS you're using, or perhaps I'm visually ignorant which does occur on occasion.